# mysql errors, with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

the error message am getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'non','','2014-07-16' )' at line
```

```
    $s_id = 'name_' . time();
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $term=$_POST['term'];
        $year=$_POST['year'];
        $m=$_POST['m'];
        $f=$_POST['f'];
        $a=$_POST['a'];
        $b=$_POST['b'];
        $c=$_POST['c'];
        $d=$_POST['d'];
        $e=$_POST['e'];
        $fa=$_POST['fa'];
        $g=$_POST['g'];
        $h=$_POST['h'];
        $i=$_POST['i'];
        $j=$_POST['j'];
        $k=$_POST['k'];
        $l=$_POST['l'];
        $ma=$_POST['ma'];
        $n=$_POST['n'];
        $o=$_POST['o'];
        $p=$_POST['p'];
        $q=$_POST['q'];
        $r=$_POST['r'];
        $s=$_POST['s'];
        $t=$_POST['t'];
        $u=$_POST['u'];
        $v=$_POST['v'];
        $w=$_POST['w'];
        $x=$_POST['x'];
        $y=$_POST['y'];
        $z=$_POST['z'];

        $az=$_POST['az'];
        $bz=$_POST['bz'];
        $cz=$_POST['cz'];
        $dz=$_POST['dz'];
        $ez=$_POST['ez'];
        $fz=$_POST['fz'];
        $gz=$_POST['gz'];
        $hz=$_POST['hz'];
        $iz=$_POST['iz'];
        $jz=$_POST['jz'];
        $kz=$_POST['kz'];
        $lz=$_POST['lz'];
        $mz=$_POST['mz'];
        $nz=$_POST['nz'];
        $oz=$_POST['oz'];
        $pz=$_POST['pz'];
        $qz=$_POST['qz'];
        $rz=$_POST['rz'];
        $sz=$_POST['sz'];
        $tz=$_POST['tz'];
        $uz=$_POST['uz'];
        $vz=$_POST['vz'];
        $wz=$_POST['wz'];
        $xz=$_POST['xz'];

        $yz=$_POST['yz'];
        $zz=$_POST['zz'];
        $ax=$_POST['ax'];
        $bx=$_POST['bx'];
        $cx=$_POST['cx'];
        $dx=$_POST['dx'];
        $ex=$_POST['ex'];
        $fx=$_POST['fx'];
        $gx=$_POST['gx'];
        $hx=$_POST['hx'];
        $ix=$_POST['ix'];
        $jx=$_POST['jx'];
        $kx=$_POST['kx'];
        $lx=$_POST['lx'];
        $mx=$_POST['mx'];
        $nx=$_POST['nx'];
        $ox=$_POST['ox'];
        $px=$_POST['px'];
        $qx=$_POST['qx'];
        $rx=$_POST['rx'];
        $sx=$_POST['sx'];
        $tx=$_POST['tx'];
        $ux=$_POST['ux'];
        $vx=$_POST['vx'];

        $wx=$_POST['wx'];
        $xx=$_POST['xx'];
        $yx=$_POST['yx'];
        $zx=$_POST['zx'];
        $ay=$_POST['ay'];
        $by=$_POST['by'];
        $cy=$_POST['cy'];
        $dy=$_POST['dy'];
        $ey=$_POST['ey'];
        $fy=$_POST['fy'];
        $gy=$_POST['gy'];
        $hy=$_POST['hy'];
        $iy=$_POST['iy'];
        $jy=$_POST['jy'];
        $ky=$_POST['ky'];
        $ly=$_POST['ly'];
        $my=$_POST['my'];
        $ny=$_POST['ny'];
        $oy=$_POST['oy'];
        $py=$_POST['py'];
        $qy=$_POST['qy'];
        $ry=$_POST['ry'];
        $sy=$_POST['sy'];
        $ty=$_POST['ty'];


        $wsh=$_POST['wsh'];
        $coded=$_POST['coded'];
        $thedate = $_POST['thedate'];

include("connect.php");


mysql_select_db("tiyende", $con);

    $query = "INSERT INTO schoolstatistic VALUES ('$s_id','$name','$term','$year','$m','$f','$a',$b','$c','$d','$e','$fa','$g','$h','$i','$j','$k','$l','$ma','$n','$o','$p','$q','$r','$s','$t','$u','$v','$w','$x','$y','$z','$az','$bz','$cz','$dz','$ez','$fz','$gz','$hz','$iz','$jz','$kz','$lz','$mz','$nz','$oz','$pz','$qz','$rz','$sz','$tz','$uz','$vz','$wz','$xz','$yz','$zz','$ax','$bx','$cx','$dx','$ex','$fx','$gx','$hx','$ix','$jx','$kx','$lx','$mx','$nx','$ox','$px','$qx','$rx','$sx','$tx','$ux','$vx','$wx','$xx','$yx','$zx','$ay','$by','$cy','$dy','$ey','$fy','$gy','$hy','$iy','$jy','$ky','$ly','$my','$ny','$oy','$py','$qy','$ry','$sy','$ty','$wsh','$coded','$thedate' )";

    if (mysql_query($query)){

        header("Location: success.php");

        }
    else {echo "Nada" . mysql_error(); }
    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Could you show us some code please?

Comment: **You have an error in your SQL syntax**. Correct it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo.

You are forgot to add the `single quotes` near `$b`

use this

```
VALUES ('$s_id','$name','$term','$year','$m','$f','$a','$b',  ....
```

instead of this

```
VALUES ('$s_id','$name','$term','$year','$m','$f','$a',$b',  .......
```

Comment: wow, thanks next2u, you know these long fields are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this correct syntax and you are forgetting '$b'

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```